# Simple Injector Webforms, property injection into masterpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, simple-injector

I have followed the setup guidelines for webforms integration and I am getting injection into Pages with no problems. But I cannot get property injection to work on a master page. I have modified the registration slightly to account for master pages but the imported properties are always null. Here are the changes I made.

```
private static void RegisterWebPages()
{
    var pageTypes =
        from assembly in BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies().Cast<Assembly>()
        where !assembly.IsDynamic
        where !assembly.GlobalAssemblyCache
        from type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()
        where type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Page)) || type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(MasterPage))
        where !type.IsAbstract && !type.IsGenericType
        select type;

    foreach (Type type in pageTypes)
    {
        var registration = Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(type, SimpleContainer);
        registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.DisposableTransientComponent, 
            "ASP.NET creates and disposes page classes for us.");
        SimpleContainer.AddRegistration(type, registration);
    }
}
```

and

```
class ImportAttributePropertySelectionBehavior : IPropertySelectionBehavior
{
    public bool SelectProperty(Type serviceType, PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        var propertyName = propertyInfo.Name;
        var isAssignable = (typeof(Page).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType) 
            || typeof(MasterPage).IsAssignableFrom(serviceType));
        var hasImportAttribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes<ImportAttribute>().Any();

        // Makes use of the System.ComponentModel.Composition assembly
        return isAssignable && hasImportAttribute;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There's an example of how to do this in the github repo: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/blob/master/src/SimpleInjector.Integration.Web.WebForms/SimpleInjectorWebFormsHttpModule.cs

Comment: I have followed that example and am getting the following exception. An exception of type 'SimpleInjector.ActivationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: No registration for type RequestDataHttpHandler could be found and an implicit registration could not be made. The constructor of type RequestDataHttpHandler contains parameter 'requestId' of type String which can not be used for constructor injection.

Comment: ok I got around that by using the filter as shown on your webforms integration page. Now I have moved all this code from test app to real app I am getting the getcontainer called on SimpleInjectorWebFormsHttpModule called before it is set in the Global.asax. Same setup in test app works fine. Anyway almost there. Thanks for the help Steven.